# how to get public IP addresses for a specific account using APIs in Amazon Web Services (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip-address, aws-api-gateway

I want to retrieve all the public IP addresses that have been allocated to an Amazon Web Services account.

Comment: Why do you seek this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of public IP addresses:

- Elastic IP addresses (static)
- Auto-assigned IP addresses (which might change if an instance is Stopped & Started)

Also, many different services are assigned IP addresses:

- Amazon EC2 instances
- Amazon RDS instances
- Amazon Elasticache instances
- Amazon Redshift instances
- Amazon EMR master node
- Elastic Load Balancer (the IP addresses change and should never be cached/stored)
- etc

You would need to perform `describe` commands against each individual service to retrieve IP address information. **There is no command that can retrieve this information across all services.**

You might be able to use an [AWS Config configuration snapshot](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/example-s3-snapshot.html) -- it might have the information you seek for most services.

**Example: Fetching Elastic IP Addresses**

The easiest way to obtain a listing of Elastic IP Addresses (which are static addresses assigned to EC2 instances) is to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), which has a [describe-addresses](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-addresses.html) command:

```
aws ec2 describe-addresses --region ap-southeast-2
```

To obtain a list of Instance IDs and IP addresses:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-addresses --region ap-southeast-2 --query 'Addresses[*].[InstanceId,PublicIp]' --output text

i-0c9c9394b3583afdc 54.222.207.37
i-0ef605853622f705e 54.79.149.39
```

The command would need to be issued for each region separately. (You could create a script that loops through them all.)

Comment: Particularly for EC2 instances, i would like to fetch all the elastic public ips. Will that be feasible by utilising any AWS APIs? If so can you share me any sources of documentation for that?

Comment: I've added an example of how to fetch Elastic IP addresses.

Comment: Hi @BalasrinivasVanapalli, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: sure thing! :) Thank you!